# Find minimum value of $f(b)$ where $f(b)$ denotes the maximum value of $g(x)$ where $g(x)=\left|\sin x+\frac{2}{3+\sin x}+b\right|$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization, contest-math, maxima-minima

> For any real number $b$ let $f(b)$ denote the maximum value of $g(x)$ where $$g(x)=\left|\sin x+\frac{2}{3+\sin x}+b\right|$$

> Find the minimum value of $f(b)$

$f(b)$ appears to be lying between $b$ and $b+\frac{3}{2}$. So what can the minimum value of $f(b)$

Comment: Call $u = \sin(x)$, minimize it for $u \in [-1,1]$. Does it helps?

Comment: $g(\frac{\pi}{2})=|b+\frac{3}{2}|$ which appears to be maximum value of $g(x)$. So can minimum value of $|b+\frac{3}{2}|$ be $\frac{3}{2}$ or will it be $0$

Comment: it will be $0$ i.e when b=$\frac{-3}{2}$

Comment: The answer is given to be $\frac{3}{4}$ which occurs when $b=-\frac{3}{4}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $t=3+\sin x$, then $2\leq t\leq 4$ so $$3\leq t+{2\over t} \leq {9\over 2}$$ and   $$g(x)= \underbrace{|t-3+{2\over t}+b|}_{=:h(t)}$$

If $b\geq 0$ then $$h(t) =  t+{2\over t}+b-3 \leq {3\over 2}+b = f(b) \implies \min f(b) = {3\over 2}$$

If $b\leq -{3\over 2}$ then $$h(t) =  -t-{2\over t}-b+3 \leq -b = f(b) \implies \min f(b) = {3\over 2}$$

If $-{3\over 2}<b<0$ then $$f(b)= \max \{h(2),h(4)\} = \max \{-b,{3\over 2}+b  \}$$

$$={{3\over 4} +|b+{3\over 4}| } \implies \boxed{\min f(b) = {3\over 4}}$$
and eqaulity is achieved at $b=-{3\over 4}$

---

Notice: I use this formula for max at the end
$$ \max\{a,b\} = {a+b+|a-b|\over 2}$$

Comment: Most elegant use of max{a,b}