# Why did he write $f_\min=3/2$?

Tags: contest-math, reference-works

I don't have much reputation to comment everywhere as as I'm new here.

Could some explain me what and why this line is being written in [this anser to "Find minimum value of $f(b)$ where $f(b)$ denotes the maximum value of $g(x)$ where $g(x)=\left|\sin x+\frac{2}{3+\sin x}+b\right|$."](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3784804/find-minimum-value-of-fb-where-fb-denotes-the-maximum-value-of-gx-wh/3784903#3784903)
I didn't really understand despite reading it several times.

If $b\leq -{3\over 2}$ then $$h(t) =  -t-{2\over t}-b+3 \leq -b = f(b) \implies \min f(b) = {3\over 2}$$

If $-{3\over 2}<b<0$ then $$f(b)= \max \{h(2),h(4)\} = \max\left\{-b,{3\over 2}+b \right\}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was stated in the answer that
$$f(b)=\max_{2\le t\le 4}h(t),\quad\text{where}\quad h(t)=\left|t+\frac2t-3+b\right|$$
and that when $t$ increases from $2$ to $4,$ $t+\frac2t$ increases from $3$ to $\frac92.$ Therefore, $t+\frac2t-3$ increases from $0$ to $\frac32,$ and
$$f(b)=\max_{0\le s\le\frac32}|s+b|.$$
If $b\le-\frac32$ then $\forall s\le\frac32\quad s+b\le0$ and
$$f(b)=\max_{0\le s\le\frac32}(-s-b)=-b.$$
If $-\frac32\le b\le0$ then $s+b$ is $\le0$ for $s\in[0,-b]$ and $\ge0$ for $s\in\left[-b,\frac32\right],$ so
$$f(b)=\max\left(\max_{0\le s\le-b}(-s-b),\max_{-b\le s\le\frac32}(s+b)\right)=\max\left(-b,\frac32+b\right).$$
Note that the value $-b$ corresponds in both cases to $s=0$ i.e. $t=2,$ and the value $\frac32+b$ (in the second case) to $s=\frac32$ i.e. $t=4:$
$$-b=h(0),\qquad\frac32+b=h(4).$$

Similarly, they found that if $b\ge0$ then $f(b)=\frac32+b,$ so that finally,
$$\min_{b\in\Bbb R}f(b)=\min\left(\min_{b\le-\frac32}-b,\min_{-\frac32\le b\le0}\max\left(-b,\frac32+b\right),\min_{b\ge0}\frac32+b\right)$$
$$=\min\left(\frac32,\frac34,\frac32\right)=\frac34.$$

Comment: According to you minimum value is $\dfrac{-3}{2}$ but answer given is $\dfrac{3}{4}$

Comment: @mathophile Many thanks!  How could I? ($f\ge0$). Just corrected.

Answer (score 1):

The answer states the bounds for $t$ between $2 \leq t \leq 4$. If $t=4$ then $$h(t)=t+\frac{2}{t}+b-3 = 4+\frac{1}{2}+b-3=\frac{3}{2}+b$$

Which means the minimum can be $\frac{3}{2}$ since the condition $b=0$ is allowed.

Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

As in the answer defined we have $h(t)=|t-3+\frac{2}{t}+b|$.
The absolute value is annoying therefore we distinct 3 cases.

For $b\geq0$ we have $t-3+\frac{2}{t}+b\geq0$.

For $b \leq -1.5$ we have $t-3+\frac{2}{t}+b\leq0$.

In both cases you can resolve the absolute value, maximize $h(t)$ and eventually minimize $f(b)$.

The question is what happens for $-1.5\leq b \leq 0$? We know that the absolute value takes its maximum on its boundaries therefore we get $\max h=\max(h(2),h(4))$ an from there on we can solve the $\min f(b)$.

Comment: Ok just a clarity needed: For b≤−1.5  we have t−3+2t+b≤0...here we req minimum val of f(b) right so the expression t−3+2t should be 1.5 and the value of b should be max so as to make f(b) min, then  1.5 - (-1.5)=3 right ?
.

Comment: For $b\leq -1.5$ we have $t-3+2/t+b \leq 0$ therefore $|t-3+2/t+b|=-(t-3+2/t+b)$. That's your expression to maximize.